# Get all the past events of the contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, web3.py

how can we get all the past events of the contract ?
I am trying like this :

**on web3.js ( "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.34"):**

```
// Add the web3 node module
var Web3 = require('web3');

// Show web3 where it needs to look for the Ethereum node.
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://mainnet.infura.io/_ws'));

// Define the contract ABI
var abi = 

// Define the contract ABI and Address
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x5a3c9A1725BB82690ee0959c89abE96fD1b527ee');

// Fun console text, you can ignore this.
console.log('-----------------------------------');
console.log('Matching Smart Contract Events');
console.log('-----------------------------------');

const filter = { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'}; // filter for your address
const events = contract.allEvents(filter); // get all events
console.log(events)

// contract.Transfer({}, { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' }).get((error, eventResult) => {
//   if (error)
//     console.log('Error in myEvent event handler: ' + error);
//   else
//     console.log('myEvent: ' + JSON.stringify(eventResult.args));
// });

// contract.allEvents(fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest', (e, res) => console.log(res))
```

**on web3.py (web3==4.3.0) :**

```
import requests
from web3 import Web3,WebsocketProvider

def main():
 web3 = Web3(WebsocketProvider("wss://mainnet.infura.io/_ws"))
 print (web3, "web3")
 contract_address = "0x5a3c9A1725BB82690ee0959c89abE96fD1b527ee"
 contract_abi = 
 contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)
 print (contract, "contract")

 transferEvent = contract.eventFilter('Transfer', {'fromBlock': 0,'toBlock': 'latest'});
 print (transferEvent, "transferEvent")

 eventlist = transferEvent.get_all_entries()
 print(eventlist, "eventlist")


 # transferEvent = contract.eventFilter('Transfer', fromBlock = 0)
 # transferEvent = contract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock = 0)
 # print (transferEvent.get_all_entries())

if __name__ == "__main__":
 print ("Script has started...")
 main()
 print ("Script has ended...")
```

Comment: This seems ok, what error are you getting?

Comment: on web3.py : *** TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: on web3.js : TypeError: contract.allEvents is not a function

Comment: I just came to know ,  there is a limit on the number of events we can get from infura.

Comment: is that was the rror consider to add an answer yourself so that the rest know this.

Comment: you are right at your point ! but what i am trying to get the address of all the token holders

Comment: Instead of using infura you could run your on node in light mode, this doesn't take many resources of your computer and yet it allows full implementations of filters

Comment: @Jaime any idea on how to run a light weighted node?

Comment: install geth, the in the console run `geth -light` that will do

Comment: something like that : geth --light --port 3000 --networkid 1 --nodiscover maxpeers=0  --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:8000" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner"

Comment: I just use the default options that why `-light` do for me

Comment: what will be the rpc address and port in geth --light ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an answer for web3.py version 5.1

Example:

```py
from web3 import Web3
from .utils import create_contract
from .events import fetch_events


uniswap_factory = '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f'
factory_abi_url = 'https://unpkg.com/@uniswap/v2-core@1.0.1/build/UniswapV2Factory.json'
erc20_abi_url = 'https://unpkg.com/@uniswap/v2-core@1.0.1/build/IERC20.json'

def fetch_uniswap_pairs(web3: Web3):
    """Fetch all trading pairs on Uniswap"""
    factory = create_contract(web3, factory_abi_url, uniswap_factory)
    events = list(fetch_events(factory.events.PairCreated, from_block=0))

    print('Got', len(events), 'events')

    # Each event.args is presented as AttrbuteDict
    # AttributeDict({'args': AttributeDict({'token0': '0x607F4C5BB672230e8672085532f7e901544a7375', 'token1': '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2', 'pair': '0x6d57a53A45343187905aaD6AD8eD532D105697c1', '': 94}), 'event': 'PairCreated', 'logIndex': 7, 'transactionIndex': 2, 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0xa0ce4b0db9bbf7887f09c4b35ec1167144b06f69fbbea6d6a163a72db28175d8'), 'address': '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f', 'blockHash': HexBytes('0xf269a89cf729781bfa8e8ec421f8eefbf13e1fecd22b4118c1304d360832ef20'), 'blockNumber': 10092190})
    for ev in events[0:10]:
      token0 = create_contract(web3, erc20_abi_url, ev.args.token0)
      token1 = create_contract(web3, erc20_abi_url, ev.args.token1)
      print(f'Found pair {token0.functions.symbol().call()}-{token1.functions.symbol().call()}')


def run():
    infura = # Your HTTPS infura endpoint URL
    web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura))
    fetch_uniswap_pairs(web3)


run()
```

Utils.py:

```
import requests

from web3 import Web3

_cache = dict()


def get_cached_abi(abi_url):
    """Per process over-the-network ABI file retriever"""
    spec = _cache.get(abi_url)
    if not spec:
      spec = _cache[abi_url] = requests.get(abi_url).json()
    return spec


def create_contract(web3, abi_url, address):
    spec = get_cached_abi(abi_url)
    contract = web3.eth.contract(address, abi=spec['abi'])
    return contract
```

events.py:

```py
from web3._utils.abi import get_constructor_abi, merge_args_and_kwargs
from web3._utils.events import get_event_data
from web3._utils.filters import construct_event_filter_params
from web3._utils.contracts import encode_abi


def fetch_events(
    event,
    argument_filters=None,
    from_block=None,
    to_block="latest",
    address=None,
    topics=None):
    """Get events using eth_getLogs API.

    This is a stateless method, as opposite to createFilter and works with
    stateless nodes like QuikNode and Infura.

    :param event: Event instance from your contract.events
    :param argument_filters:
    :param from_block: Start block. Use 0 for all history/
    :param to_block: Fetch events until this contract
    :param address:
    :param topics:
    :return:
    """

    if from_block is None:
        raise TypeError("Missing mandatory keyword argument to getLogs: from_Block")

    abi = event._get_event_abi()
    abi_codec = event.web3.codec

    # Set up any indexed event filters if needed
    argument_filters = dict()
    _filters = dict(**argument_filters)

    data_filter_set, event_filter_params = construct_event_filter_params(
        abi,
        abi_codec,
        contract_address=event.address,
        argument_filters=_filters,
        fromBlock=from_block,
        toBlock=to_block,
        address=address,
        topics=topics,
    )

    # Call node over JSON-RPC API
    logs = event.web3.eth.getLogs(event_filter_params)

    # Convert raw binary event data to easily manipulable Python objects
    for entry in logs:
        data = get_event_data(abi_codec, abi, entry)
        yield data
```

Answer (score 1):

[web3-ethereum-defi package](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi) now has [a ultra fast concurrent event reader using thread pools](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/_autosummary_block_reader/eth_defi.event_reader.reader.read_events_concurrent.html#eth_defi.event_reader.reader.read_events_concurrent). It can read multiple events over block ranges using concurrency and maximizing the potential performance over JSON-RPC API.

Here is an example how to use:

```py
        json_rpc_url = os.environ["JSON_RPC_URL"]
        web3_factory = TunedWeb3Factory(json_rpc_url)
        web3 = web3_factory(token_cache)
        executor = create_thread_pool_executor(web3_factory, max_workers=16)

        # Get contracts
        Factory = get_contract(web3, "UniswapV2Factory.json")

        # You can scan multiple events once
        events = [
            Factory.events.PairCreated,
        ]

        start_block = 10_000_835  # Uni deployed
        end_block = 10_009_000  # The first pair created before this block

        # Read through the blog ran
        out = []
        for log_result in read_events_concurrent(
            executor,
            start_block,
            end_block,
            events,
            None,
            chunk_size=100,
            context=token_cache,
            extract_timestamps=None,
        ):
            out.append(decode_pair_created(log_result))
```

[See full example](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/master/scripts/read-uniswap-v2-pairs-and-swaps-concurrent.py).